# better solution then a timeout for normalization delay

Tags: javascript

I have to use this timeout, because submit gets fired before the normalization method finishish. This feels really sloppy, is there a better way?

```js
        let submitButton = document.getElementById("hidden-submit");
        cleanFileName = files[0].name.normalize('NFD').replace(/\p{Diacritic}/gu, "");
        setTimeout(() => {
            submitButton.click();
        }, 10)
```

Comment: Are you sure that’s what’s happening?

Comment: @DaveNewton Yeah, cause once I remove the timeout it doesn't work anymore, I can't see another reason. I am using Svelte and binding the cleanFileName to an input. My s3 bucket can't handle Spanish characters

Comment: Clean the filename in a change event, or use a click event with a type="button" (rather than type="submit") button

Comment: @user2182349 This for drag and drop upload situation. Also its inside the change events.

Comment: I suspect you have not yet identified the underlying issue. More code might help diagnosis.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use `Promise` :

```js
new Promise(submitButton.click)
```

Or the `window.onload` method depending on the exact beahaviour you want :

```js
window.onload = () => {
  const submitButton = document.getElementById("hidden-submit");
  cleanFileName = files[0].name.normalize('NFD').replace(/\p{Diacritic}/gu, "");
  submitButton.click();
}
```